# Find given day of supplied date's week in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some dates in a column, and would like to, using the dates in that column i.e I would like to produce the first column, based on what is in the second

```
Week Starting   Date
01/11/2009  01/11/2009
01/11/2009  02/11/2009
01/11/2009  03/11/2009
01/11/2009  04/11/2009
01/11/2009  05/11/2009
01/11/2009  06/11/2009
01/11/2009  07/11/2009
08/11/2009  08/11/2009
08/11/2009  09/11/2009
08/11/2009  10/11/2009
08/11/2009  11/11/2009
08/11/2009  12/11/2009
08/11/2009  13/11/2009
08/11/2009  14/11/2009
15/11/2009  15/11/2009
15/11/2009  16/11/2009
15/11/2009  17/11/2009
15/11/2009  18/11/2009
15/11/2009  19/11/2009
15/11/2009  20/11/2009
15/11/2009  21/11/2009
22/11/2009  22/11/2009
22/11/2009  23/11/2009
22/11/2009  24/11/2009
```

Is there a formula to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Weekday returns an index number for the day of the week, so you can use the following to get the start of the week:

=B1-(WEEKDAY(B1)-1)